# How does git, for example, create the database they use?

Tags: c, git, shell, command-line, terminal

Hi so I am working on a terminal application and would like to use a database. I am not sure the best way to go about doing it though.

So I want to have the program be able to install like you would git or with brew install etc. And then each person that installs it would have their own database which will be accessed via certain commands.

I'm just not sure what the best way to do this would be? I was thinking for each entry I would put in the database I could just create a file in a .directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filesystem is actually quite a good database, suitable for storing a moderate number of documents with sizes ranging from tiny to huge. It's not relational (the only "key" is the file name), and it's actually closer to a "NoSQL" database than a relational database.

The Git database, in fact, can store all its objects with one object per file. However, for efficiency reasons, it was found that the access patterns required by Git were better served by combining many objects into one "pack" file.

Comment: **But** the filesystem has many problems when compared to a real database. What happens when the computer crashes halfway while writing? Does Git protect against these things like Sqlite does?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, Git's on-disk data structures are designed to support atomic updates. Git is built upon the filesystem just like Sqlite is built upon the filesystem. Although they take a different approach to atomic updates, they are both designed to be robust in the event of system crashes.

Comment: Ic, I was under the impression that Sqlite is [more crash-tolerant and data integrity-ed](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28702/9405)  than Git. Does Git do write ahead loggings too?

Comment: @Pacerier: Git doesn't need to, because its data structures are immutable. When Git makes a change to the repository, it writes all the underlying data first (which is always new, not changing existing data) and then updates a pointer (such as a branch head) to point to the new data. It's a restricted use case that is designed to be robust without having all the extra machinery required of a general purpose relational database.

Comment: So are you saying that when we need a "write-only" database, Git is actually **faster** than **real** generic-purpose databases like MySQL, pgSQL and etc?

Comment: @Pacerier: I make no claim about speed. Perhaps what I am saying is that if you need a robust disk-based data structure for storing source code revisions, Git is a fine example of an implementation. (That's what this question and answer is about, not about comparing Git and SQLite.)

Answer (score 1):

Git has a much different "database" scheme than other applications. As visualized [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is), it has a .git directory, with a objects/ directory and a bunch of files named after SHA checksums. This is not a very good model to use for someone who is starting out.

If you want to use the Git filesystem, there are ways to do that (search for "git plumbing").

I'd recommend one of MySQL, XML files, or a filesystem format (keep in mind, if you run on Windows, anything below 4KB is wasting space).

Comment: What does running on Windows have to do with "below 4 kB wasting space"? This some complaint about block sizes on hard drives, that NTFS, ext3/4 use? With the advent of Advanced Format, 4k is practically required as the minimum block size.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely looking for SQLite.